# Exact dates in mercurial web inteface

Tags: mercurial

While working with Mercurial repository through web interface, time is mostly shown as spans specifying how long ago something happens: "1 minute/hour/day ago". Is there a way to make web interface output exact date in some specific or local timezone instead, without touching any configuration files? Perhaps some query parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Humorously enough, the exact dates are what's in the HTML, but then they're converted to relative dates by javascript.  That's done for caching purposes (exact dates are always the same for everyone, but relative times vary by response).  So your easiest route is to disable or block javascript on that page.  Barring that you'll need to edit the theme file to exclude the time-relativizing javascript.

Comment: Kind of thought so. Well, it seems a little userscript can help as well.